# Referencing in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to reference this cell in another worksheet for my current worksheet, which is calculated by

`=[2015_RunRate.xlsx]January!$C$66`

However, I want to replace the word "January" in that reference with the value from cell C19 in my current worksheet.

I tried something along the lines of:

`=([2015_RunRate.xlsx])([Current_Worksheet.xlsx]!$C$19)!$C$66`

That clearly didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) to convert a string you've stitched together into a valid cell reference.

```
=INDIRECT("[2015_RunRate.xlsx]"&$C$19&"!C66")
```

The INDIRECT function cannot reference a closed workbook. It is also considered a volatile¹ function. Since `C66` is now nothing but text that looks like a cell reference, there is no need to add the absolute row and column indicators (e.g. **$**). The text will not change when moved or copied to another location.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Great. Worked for me and saved me literally hours of work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Indirect function. E.g.:

`INDIRECT("[Book2.xlsx]"&B1&"!$A$1")`

Where B1 is a cell containing text string with name of a sheet in the other workbook. Like "January", "February", etc.